# Custom design - issue with date (Please enter a valid date.)

Tags: date

When I try to change a date for custom design, I receive the following error message. "Please enter a valid date.". I'm enclosing the image. I'm using 1.9.2 version of Magento.

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: What locale is the store set to and are you manually entering the dates or using the widget? The error you are seeing is most probably due to the date format not matching that of the locale.

Comment: Store is set to BS_BA (Bosnian). And yes I'm using the widget. Is there a way I can enter  manually the date in the format which will work? thanks

Comment: try using dd.mm.yyyy for 10.11.2015 for example. Notice you have an extra period (.) after the year

Comment: I just tried to enter dd.mm.yyyy as you suggested, but error sill remains.

Comment: If this is a dev store, have you tried changing the locale to another region?

Comment: i'm affraid i'm not able to change the locale to another region. I found the following: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/date-validation-not-working-conflict-with-date-picker?rq=1

but I'm not sure where to change this!

Comment: Try changing the admin interface in the bottom left hand corner of the admin (this will just change the interface not the locale). I have attempted to recreate this with using bosnian locale and am not having trouble. What sub version of 1.9.2 are you using?

Comment: Thank you Erik, i change the interface to EN, now the date picker is working. Now, how come, that new custom design is not applayed when set the date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32009/discussion-between-user15151-and-eirik).